# I want to use same observer in extension both module what I do?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, event-observer, package

I have created `package1` and its 2 modules for example module1,module2.Now situation is I want to use both observer in both modules,I want to run first module1 observer then call or run second module observer.Both modules are using same observer.What I do ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `depends`. In your second module registration file (i.e. **app/etc/modules/Package1_Module2.xml**) after:

```
    <codePool>...</codePool>
```

add something like this:

```
    <depends>
        <Package1_Module1/>
    </depends>
```